# powershell script to export all groups and members and the groups with in the group members

Tags: powershell

I'm new to scripting but I'm trying to get an export.xlsx of the all of the AD groups and their members and the groups within the group.

AD group name> group Members>... and if there are AD group(s) with in the group> export the members of that AD group

So far i have the following.

```
$groups = Get-adgroup -filter * -searchbase 'OU...DC=com'

foreach($group in $groups){
    Get-adgroupmember $group |
        select samaccountname |
            export-csv C:\Temp\$group.csv -notype
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you’re getting all the groups then you shouldn’t need to get the groups within the groups as you would already have them. Right?

Comment: I need the group members of the nested group as well. For example, I may have a group with a nested group(s) that may  50+ users in it. (audit purposes)

Comment: Did you find the Answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter *

foreach($group in $groups){
    $FileName = $group.Name
    Get-Adgroupmember -Identity $group |
            Export-CSV C:\Temp\$FileName.csv -notype
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good time for a recursive function.

```
Function Get-GroupMember
{
    Param
    (
        $Group
    )

    $allmembers = foreach($member in Get-ADGroupMember $Group)
    {
        if($member.objectClass -eq 'Group')
        {
            Get-GroupMember -Group $member
        }
        else
        {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Group  = $Group.name
                Member = $member.SamAccountName
                Type   = $member.objectClass
            }
        }
    }

    $allmembers | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\$($Group.name).csv" -notype
}
```

Call it like this

```
$groups = Get-adgroup -filter * -searchbase 'OU...DC=com'

Get-GroupMember -Group $groups
```

You didn't clearly specify what all info you wanted to export. The default object would have distinguishedname, name, objectClass, objectGUID, SamAccountName, and SID. If you want all those you could change the else portion to simply "$member". Otherwise, you can adjust what the custom object returns. This will create 1 file per group named groupname.csv. You could parameterize the export path as a next step.